# Laravel pagination Error

Tags: php, laravel-5, pagination, laravel-pagination

I want to paginate a array with LengthAwarePaginator in Laravel.

When I try navigate between pages, laravel shows this error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161
```

This is my code:

```
 //$queries1 is an array.
    $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();
    $collection = new Collection($queries1);
    $currentPageSearchResults = $collection->slice($currentPage * 5, 5)->all();
    $paginatedSearchResults= new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageSearchResults, count($collection), 5);

    //configure Path
    $paginatedSearchResults->setPath(App::getLocale().'/activity/search_Activity');

    return view(App::getLocale().'.activities.ActivityResults', ['results' => $paginatedSearchResults]);
```

If I don't set the path, the link of the pagination, automatically redirect to '/'

What could be happening?

Thanks for help